# Angular: How to get async data for template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following problem:

I want to make a table with entries (Obj). And some of them have a file attribute.
If they have a file attribute (entry.file) I want to make a backend call to get the url of that file:

```
public getFileURL(archiveID: string, documentID: string, sysID: string){
    const request: FileRequest = {
      archiveID: archiveID,
      documentID: documentID,
      sysID: sysID
    };
    this.fileService.file(request).subscribe(response => {
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }
    })
}
```

This is called like: getFileURL(entry.file.archiveID, entry.file.documentID, entry.file.sysID)
And it should return an Observable, so I can check if i got a backend response.

```
<tr *ngFor="let entry of period.claims; let i = index">
...
<td>
  <div *ngIf="entry.file">
    <div *ngIf="fileClientService.getFileURL(entry.file.archiveID, entry.file.documentID, entry.file.sysID) | async as file; else loading">
      <a target="about:blank" class="download" (click)="clickLink(file)"></a>
    </div>
    <ng-template #loading let-file>loading..</ng-template>
  </div>
</td>
```

All I want is to display "loading" until the url is loaded and then display the a-tag.
Also, the url parameter coming back from the backend could be empty. So i also need to display nothing if the url is empty ("").
At the moment it fires hundred of backend calls for 2 objects with the entry.file property :(

I am not that good with Observables and I hope someone can help me with that.
Thank you so far :)

Comment: What issue are you facing in the code above?

Comment: I highly recommend to map the file object beforehand with switchMap to the url.

Comment: It produces hundred of Backend Calls per Minute. But it should only call once per URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return Observable directly from your method and map your `period.claims` into one Observable:

```js
// add proper type
entries: Observable<...> = getEntries();

getEntries() {
  // we map every claim to Observable returned from getFileURL method
  const entries = period.claims.map(entry => 
    getFileURL(...).pipe(
      // we use map to return whole entry from Observable - not only url
      map(url => ({
        ...entry,
        url,
      }))
  ));
  // forkJoin will return one Observable with value array when each Observable is completed
  return forkJoin(...entries);
}

public getFileURL(archiveID: string, documentID: string, sysID: string): Observable<...> {
    const request: FileRequest = {
      archiveID: archiveID,
      documentID: documentID,
      sysID: sysID
    };
    return this.fileService.file(request).pipe(filter(Boolean));
}
```

If you want not to pass to template empty response you could use **filter** operator and pass Boolean as callback. It will return only truthy values. You can read more about it: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter
You can read also more about `forkJoin`: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Note that adding proper type to method would tell you what you're doing wrong ;)

Comment: This also calls the Backend hundred of times. Why do you use the Observable<File> ?
The return of fileService.file() is {url: "url"}

Comment: Also I dont understand the 'as file' property. Does it mean i can use the return value of the ngIf? like: when getFileURL() returns a value can i use this return as file then? (e.g. file.url)

Comment: Add property `fileUrl` and use it in template to avoid multiple method invoking - I've edited answer. Type File could be anything. It's just an example.

Comment: I would do that, but i could have multiple fileURL. If I had just one, i could use it with fileUrl = getFileURL(...); and then this.fileURL. Do I need to build an array to keep more fileURL?

Comment: You mean API could return multiple urls? Or you mean that you need url for every `entry`? I would map `period.claims` and make it one Observable.

Comment: I mean that I need an url for every entry. ```period.claims``` is also from a ngfor above and its also data from an API call. I dont want to break the exiting code.

Comment: Can't i just say:
Call API and when value is returned display something and use return value to call a function. Why is this so hard :/

Comment: @micro I've refactored my answer. This should match your requirements. After all you can use `entries` in template

Comment: Thank you :)
It works in a sandbox scenario. We have a general templating problem in the project, that is currently the reason why i got hundredy of API calls. Our templates are loaded severall times even while or when scrolling over the page. So I actually had two problems.

Comment: Also forkjoin is awesome :D